# Installing 64-bit Weblogic on Windows 2008

Tags: weblogic

There do not appear to be procedures laid out for how to install Weblogic on Windows 2008 when you want to use the 64-bit JVM. Can anyone point me to procedures for this? The documentation appears to only exist for solaris/linux/*nix OSes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On [this page](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E13196_01/platform/suppconfigs/configs/windows2008/win2008_103.html) at the bottom there are two sections for installing Weblogic on Windows 2008 ("Download and Installation Instructions for Windows 2008 on 64-bit Xeon/AMD64" and "Download and Installation Instructions for Windows 2008 on x86").